# need to update field with condition in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am doing currently doing as

```
if (part.qty) {
      part.status = 'In Stock';
    }

    const part = new partsModel(part);
    return part.save();
```

is it possible do this in MongoDB query only without using if statement both insert and update

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
const filterObj = {
    "$or": [{
        "qty": {
            "$exists": true
        }
    }, {
        "qty": {
            "$ne": null
        }
    }, {
        "qty": {
            "$ne": 0              //based on what type of value you have in qty
        }
    }]
};

const updateObj = {
    "$set": {
        "status": "In Stock"
    }
};
partsModel.update(filterObj, updateObj)
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

This will update the first matching record with our filters. If you wanna update all matching records use **updateMany()** instead.

Check out the official mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating) for more details.

P.s: You may need some modifications as i couldn't get a chance to try the code. hope this helps :)